# How to update product qty in cart?

Tags: magento2

It's doesn't work, but I need it done with this code, is it possible?

```
public function setProdQty($customerId,$upQty,$sendId){

    $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customerId);

    $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
    $quote->setitemId($sendId);
    $quote->setqty($upQty);
    return $quote->save();

 }
```

Comment: ```$quote->setItemId($sendId)```
```$quote->setQty($upQty)```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
    echo $cartId=$cart->getQuote()->getId();

    $itemId = 720;
    $itemQty = 1;

    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
    $cartitems = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    $cartitems->setquoteId($cartId);
    $cartitems->setitemId($itemId);
    $cartitems->setqty($itemQty);

    $quoteItems[] = $cartitems;
    $quote->setItems($quoteItems);
    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
    $quote->collectTotals();
```

Comment: i want change cart product qty from dashboard, $cartId=$cart->getQuote()->getId(); returns null , this way doesn't work . How can i get each customer and update his cart product qty with this code ?

Comment: would you like to update on customer quote admin?

Comment: I created my custom list, and there I show the card information for each customer, and from there I want to change the quantity of goods in the basket for a specific customer.